# Python criteria based dynamic function adding to class

Tags: python, metaprogramming, python-2.7, python-2.6, python-2.x

How to add functions to a class dynamically based on some criteria.

For ex i have a class as follwos:

```
class A(object):
     def __init__(self,type):
         self.type = type
```

Now based on the 'type' value i want to add functions from either class B or class C to the class A.

For ex.

```
lass B(object):
    def fun1(self):
        print 'fun1'
    def fun2(self):
        print 'fun2'

class C(object):
    def fun3(self):
        print 'fun3'
    def fun4(self):
        print 'fun4'
```

If 'type' attribute value of class A is 'B' then dynamically add functions of class B (i.e. fun1 and fun2) to class A or else if 'type' attribute value is 'C' then add functions of class C to class A (i.e. fun3 and fun4) to class A, such that at further in my code i can access those functions as A.fun1() or A.fun3.

I am guessing that metaprograming might hekp me in this but i dont have a clue as to how to do it. Please guide.

Further i have to create objects of class A and be able to use these functions via those objects of class A.

```
a = class A(type='B')
a.fun1()  #should work
```

Kindly help as i am not able to figure this out.

This is the part of my code.

```
class Group(object):
    def __init__(self,type):
        if type == 'source'
            self.mgr = SManager(self)             #grp_mgr
        elif type == 'target'
            self.mgr = TManager(self)

    def __getattr__(self,name):
        if hasattr(self.mgr,name):
            return getattr(self.mgr,name)
        return AttributeError

class SManager(object):
    def __init__(self,groupobj):
        self.some_list = []
        self.groupobj = groupobj

    def doProcess(self):
        #this function accesses self.groupobj
        pass

    def get_valid_list(self):
        #this function accesses self.groupobj
        pass
```

But with this i am getting the following error.

```
    if hasattr(self.mgr,name):
  File "c:\workspace\project\dev.py", line 27, in __ge
tattr__
    if hasattr(self.mgr,name):
  File "c:\workspace\project\dev.py", line 27, in __ge
tattr__
    if hasattr(self.mgr,name):
  File "c:\workspace\project\dev.py", line 27, in __ge
tattr__
    if hasattr(self.mgr,name):
  File "c:\workspace\project\dev.py", line 27, in __ge
tattr__
    if hasattr(self.mgr,name):
  File "c:\workspace\project\dev.py", line 27, in __ge
tattr__
    if hasattr(self.mgr,name):
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I am not able to figure out as to where i am making a mistake. Before incorporating this i tried this example with a simple snippet which worked but when i did the same in actual code it is throwing error.
Pls help

Comment: *"Metaclasses are deeper magic than 99% of users should ever worry about. **If you wonder whether you need them, you don't.**"* - TP. Would you care to explain **why you need that kind of behaviour?** Maybe there's a better design on which we could help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already told in a question comment: **you probably don't need metaclasses at all.**

But since you're not giving more information, this is how what you're asking could be done with metaclasses:

```
class MetaX(type):

    def __add__(cls, other):
        name = '{}+{}'.format(cls.__name__, other.__name__)
        return type(cls)(name, (cls, other), dict())


class X(object):    # metaclass=MetaX in py3k

    __metaclass__ = MetaX

    def __add__(self, other):
        cls = type(self) + type(other)
        return cls
```

That's it, you'll just need to inherit from `X`.

Example:

```
class A(X):
    def func_a(self):
        print "I'm in func_a"

class B(X):
    def func_b(self):
        print "I'm in func_b"

class C(X):
    def func_c(self):
        print "I'm in func_c"

L = A + B
l = L()
l.func_a()  # -> I'm in func_a
l.func_b()  # -> I'm in func_b

P = A + C
p = P()
p.func_a()  # -> I'm in func_a
p.func_c()  # -> I'm in func_c
```

**Edit:** What you really need depends on how your actual code looks like.

What you described in your question is a *dynamic inheritance*, if that's what you really need, then IMO a metaclass is the right tool and overriding __getattr__ it would be just a hack.

If you don't want to build a whole metaclass you could build just use some kind of class factory:

```
def get_enhanced_A(typ)   # you can't use type as a keyword here
    dct = {'B': B, 'C': C}
    return type('A+{}'.format(typ), (A,dct[typ]), dict())
```

I wouldn't know which one of the two options looks better.

Comment: Thanks. The getattr overriding as mentioned by zeekay seems easier than yours, but even this was really helpful. This would be my second bet. Thanks :)

Comment: Also as you mnetioned that you need more info. Please let me know what more info that you need about my question and i will convey the same here. thanks

Comment: @PyBegginer: What you described in your question sounds like *dynamic inheritance*, doing that overriding \_\_getattr__ looks like a hack. But the main point is if you really need such dynamic behaviour? Couldn't a better design be found? You didn't show your code, so we're a little in the dark.

Comment: i have edited my question and added my code snippet. Kindly have a look

Answer (score 3):

Seems like your question is [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341), and solution to your original problem "X" is multiple inheritance, like:

```
class A(B, C):
    pass
```

So now you are able to do `A().fun1()` as well as `A().fun3()`.

Comment: I had actually thought of this. But in my case i need either the functions of class B or class C but never of both.

Comment: @PyBegginer: If you need the functions of A or B but not both, then only inherit from one of them; you can then pass the appropriate class to whatever code needs to instantiate such objects.

Answer (score 1):

Roman's answer is probably the sanest approach. But hey let's overlook that and think about some crazy things you could do instead!

You could just use a function, but that's too easy:

```
def A(type):
    if type == 'B':
        return B()
    elif type == 'C':
        return C
```

You could override `__getattr__` so that missing attributes are looked up on an instance of the class chosen:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, type):
        if type == 'B':
            self.type = B()
        if type == 'C':
            self.type = C()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if hasattr(self.type, name):
            return getattr(self.type, name)
        return AttributeError
```

Or you could override `__new__`, and return a some crazy new class, or an instance of the class you are interested in:

```
class A(object):
    bases = {'B': B, 'C': C}

    def __new__(cls, type):
        class Cls(A.bases[type]):
            pass
        return Cls()
```

And probably a lot of other misguided things!

Comment: the idea with getattr sounds good enough for my purpose. Thanks :)

Comment: I am getting the following error with this method.                  'if hasattr(self.grp_mgr,name):
      File "c:\workspace\project\trial.py", line 27, in __getattr__
        if hasattr(self.type,name):
    RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object'

Comment: i have edited my question adding my code snippet. Kindly have a look.